# Fluid Design - border-radius: 10px on an img

Tags: html, css

I'm working with DW:CC, using a fluid design layout.  I have an  main_image, and would like to have the borders rounded on the image.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
<article class="fluid main_image hide_mobile">
    <img src="images/placeholder 3 to 2.jpg" alt=""/>
</article>
```

CSS:

```
.main_image {
    margin-top: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.main_image img{
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to apply the border radius to the `<img>`.

```
.main_image img{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Interesting - I thought I tried that as well.  I must have messed it up somehow.  It's working now.  Thanks!